# Retrieving values from sqlite database for every month

Tags: android, sqlite

```
select * from balance  where value = '"+value+"' order by date DESC LIMIT 1
```

How to select the values of row for every month endings..the above code only gives the first value of date...but I am in need for every months's first value....which is stored in timestamp

Answer (score 0):

First, use max() instead of ORDER BY:

```
SELECT max(date)
FROM balance
WHERE value = ?
```

Then you can use GROUP BY to get the largest date for each month (`%Y%m` outputs year and month, i.e., is unique for each month):

```
SELECT max(date)
FROM balance
WHERE value = ?
GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m')
```

Then you can use these dates to filter the original table:

```
SELECT *
FROM balance
WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date)
               FROM balance
               WHERE value = ?
               GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m'))
```